# Login with curl in a Magento site

Tags: login, curl

I'm trying to login in a Magento site with curl against a form like this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/es/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post" id="login-form">
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="9CR1ydcbOTl9p31r" />
<ul class="form-list">
    <li>
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="" id="email"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="login[password]" id="pass" title="Password" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

With this script, I get the `form_key` value and sent the login request, with a powershell script in this way:

```
$formkey = curl.exe -c cookie_urban -s http://www.example.com/es/customer/account/login | Select-String -Pattern ‘value="([A-Za-z0-9]{16,})"‘ | %{$_ -replace '        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="', ''} | %{$_ -replace '" />', ''}

curl.exe --cookie "user_allowed_save_cookie=%7B%221%22%3A1%7D" --referer http://www.example.com/es/customer/account/login --user-agent "Mozilla/4.73 [en] (X11; U; Linux 2.2.15 i686)" -b cookie_urban -L -H "Origin: http://www.example.com" --data-urlencode "form_key=$($formkey)&login[username]=email@gmail.com&login[password]=password&send=" http://www.example.com/es/customer/account/loginPost > result.html
```

The parameters that you see are taken by the developer console of my browser. The problem is that when I click on result.html I can't see that I logged in, why? If you have an explanation please tell me. If you have a solution with another language, tell me!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you can't see signs of being logged in is that the `loginPostAction` from the `AccountController` redirects in case of any errors or also after the customer data was added to the session.

I don't know how or if it's possible to catch such a redirect with curl but this seems to be needed.

Comment: So, what do you suggest? If you have a different solution that use wget o something else, please tell me!

Comment: I don't even know what you're trying to achieve with the curl request.

Comment: I'm simply log into the site and then perform such operations as loggedin user.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` does not handle sessions or store cookies, so one cannot "login" with `curl` to perform any operations as the logged on user. Instead, browser automation tools such as [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) could be used, or a headless web browser. But the best solution would be to use Magento's [REST API](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/).